# How to process all nodes in a Nodelist

Tags: java, xml, recursion, nodelist

i am trying to process all nodes in a node list and replace special characters in the text.

The issue i face is that i need to return an object which contains all the values replaced. If i use recursion this is not possible to return a value right?

How can i iterate a xml nodelist processing all elements and removing special characters? My apporach at the moment is to do this

```
public static IXMLDatagram removeIllegalCharsFromDataGram(IXMLDatagram dg, String[] illegalValues)
{
    NodeList nodeList = dg.getAsDOMElement().getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength() ; i++)
    {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {

            for(String replaceChar : illegalValues)
            {
                // do something with the current element
                if(node.getTextContent().contains(replaceChar))
                {
                    node.setTextContent(node.getTextContent().replace(replaceChar, ""));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dg;
}
```

But this doesn't take account of child nodes which change regularly in these documents and are often nested quite deep

Thanks

Comment: You could pre-iterate all the nodes/lists, placing them all in a `List` of some kind, then process the `List` instead

Comment: and then how would i replace the nodes back in the original object?

Comment: Why would you need to?  You're modifying the physical objects contents, they've not been removed from the DOM, you're just maintaining a reference to them...

Comment: interesting, let me try this approach

Answer (score 0):

A recursion is often the simplest approach for deep processing of DOMs:

```
public static void removeIllegalCharsFromDataGram(IXMLDatagram dg,
        String[] illegalValues) {
    Node root = dg.getAsDOMElement().getDocumentElement();
    removeIllegal(illegalValues, root);
}
private static void removeIllegal(String[] illegalValues, Node root) {
    NodeList nodeList = root.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);

        removeIllegal(illegalValues,node);//<-- Call for every child

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            for (String replaceChar : illegalValues) {
                // do something with the current element
                if (node.getTextContent().contains(replaceChar)) {
                    node.setTextContent(node.getTextContent().replace(
                            replaceChar, ""));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```